# Find guaranteed ancestors in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to find what I call 'guaranteed ancestors' in a directed graph. I have a list of nodes which each can point to zero, one or multiple child nodes.

Below you see an example of a simple graph. I've marked all circles with a unique number.

Let's imagine we're trying to determine which nodes I'm guaranteed to have visited before reaching node 13 starting at node 0.

[image]

My thoughts when solving this simple example by hand is starting in node 13 and working my way back, which nodes am I guaranteed to visit no matter which direction I go. The first node I notice obeying this property is node 10, since no matter if I choose to visit node 11 or node 12, then I'm guaranteed to eventually reach node 13. Similarly I can conclude I have to visit node 9 if I want to reach node 13. Working all the way up the graph I conclude that node 13 has node 0, 1, 9, 10 as it's guaranteed anchestors.

I'm not sure what such an algorithm is called, but I'm sure there is a name for this specific search.

Here is the constraints you can assume about my graph.

1. There is a single defined "head/root" node, which is the only node without any other nodes pointing to it.
2. The graph is acyclic (Ideally the algorithm would be able to handle cycles too, but I have a different check, verifying that the graph is acyclic, so this is not a must.)
3. There is no "dead" nodes, eg. nodes which can't be reached from the head/root node.

This has to run on more complicated graphs with up to 500 nodes and many nodes with multiple "parents", which could be connected back and forth. Runtime is a priority as well - I assume we should be able to solve this problem in linear time complexity.

I've tried simplifying the problem to the point where I tried making an algorithm which could determine if a single node was a guaranteed anchestor of another node, which I believe is pretty simple to determine in O(n), however if I want a complete list of all guaranteed anchestors I assume I'd have to run this algorithm for every node, leaving me with O(n^2).

Does anyone know the correct name of the algorithm I'm describing?

Comment: This looks like something from project planning.  These are critical nodes.

Comment: "Guaranteed ancestors" are known as "dominators", and what you're looking for is called the "dominator tree": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory), https://tanujkhattar.wordpress.com/2016/01/11/dominator-tree-of-a-directed-graph/

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign a weight of 1 to every edge
2. Run Dijkstra to find shortest path between head and root.
3. Assign weight of 2 * ( edge count of graph ) to every edge in path
4. Run Dijkstra to find cheapest path
5. Identify edges that are present in both paths. ( they could not be avoided although very expensive )
6. The nodes at both ends of every edge identified in 5 will be critical - i.e they must ALL be visted by any route between head and root.

Consider an example:

[image]

The first Dijkstra run would return a path containing node 1 or 2 ( they both belong on 5 hop paths.  The second run would return  a path containing  the other of those two nodes

Comment: This might also return non-critical nodes. Consider the following graph: https://i.imgur.com/QFQaded.png The non-weighted shortest path from top-node to bottom-node passes through all four red nodes; Any path has to pass through at least one of the four red nodes, although none is individually critical.

Comment: @stef The algorithm I posted would return zero critical nodes.  The first Dijkstra run would return either the extreme left or extreme right red node.  The second would return the other.  So neithr would be marked critical in step 5

Comment: Oops. I messed up the graph. Imagine there are only 3 red nodes instead of 4. Then the path going through all three red nodes would be only 4-hops, whereas any path using only 1 of the red nodes would be 5-hops at minimum.

Comment: Actually, even on the graph I drew, the first run of the Dijsktra algorithm might return the path going through all four red nodes, if we're unlucky.

Comment: Thanks for your input! If I'm not mistaken, then what you have identified is a subset of vertices where doing from head to root, you have to pass at least one of the nodes in the subset. What I'm actually trying to do is identify the subset of all the nodes you can't avoid visiting, no matter which path to take along the graph. I see some of you mentioning critical nodes, perhaps that's really what I'm looking for.

Comment: @TobiasKnudsen The algorithm is designed to identify a subset of the nodes, ALL of which have to be visited.

Comment: @stef I have modified the algorithm to handle your counter-examples.

Comment: @ravenspoint Although I don't have a counterexample to the new algorithm off the top of my head, I also believe that such an algorithm deserves a (sketch of a) proof of correctness.

Comment: @Stef I will leave that to the academic types - it sounds like the sort of thing they enjoy.

Comment: The problem is, we can't just trust your word that the algorithm does what you say it does. It obviously returns a list of nodes, yes, but are those the nodes we want? You already "patched" your previous attempt to make it work on the counter-example which I found (I did not have difficulty finding it, I must say - it was the first example I tried); what tells us that the new version of the algorithm won't fail on the next example we try it on? It's not just "the academic types" who want algorithms to work. Quite a lot of effort is spent in the industry to make sure that things work.

Comment: I am not asking anyone to "trust" my word!  I am suggesting an algorithm that looks like it might be useful.  I am willing to engage with anyone who wants to discuss it.  Isn't that what this site is about?   Making suggestions and then having them tested is what is called the Scientific Method.  It is usually considered a worthwhile activity!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost what the definition of an articulation or cut vertex is in an undirected graph. See [Biconnected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component):

> a cut vertex is any vertex whose removal increases the number of connected components.

The difference is that your graph is directed, and that you consider the root also as such a vertex.

So my suggestion is to temporarily consider the graph to be undirected, and to apply a depth-first algorithm to identify such cut vertices, and include the root.

The algorithm is given as pseudo code in the [same Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component#Pseudocode). I have rewritten it in JavaScript, so it can be run here for the graph that you have given as example:

```js
function buildAdjacencyList(n, edges) {
    // Indexes in adj represent node identifiers. 
    // Values in adj are lists of neighbors: start out with empty lists
    let adj = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) adj.push([]);
    for (let [start, end] of edges) {
        adj[start].push(end  );
        adj[end  ].push(start); // make edge bidirectional
    }
    return adj;
}

function markArticulationPoints(nodes, node, depth) {
    node.visited = true;
    node.depth = depth;
    node.low = depth;
    for (let neighborId of node.neighbors) {
        let neighbor = nodes[neighborId];
        if (!neighbor.visited) {
            neighbor.parent = node;
            markArticulationPoints(nodes, neighbor, depth + 1);
            if (neighbor.low >= node.depth) node.isArticulation = true;
            if (neighbor.low < node.low) node.low = neighbor.low;
        } else if (neighbor != node.parent && neighbor.depth < node.low) {
            node.low = neighbor.depth;
        }
    }
}
    
function getArticulationPoints(adj, root) {
    // Create object for each node, having meta data for algorithm
    let nodes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < adj.length; i++) {
        nodes.push({
            neighbors: adj[i],
            visited: false,
            depth: Infinity,
            low: Infinity,
            parent: -1,
            isArticulation: i == root // root is considered articulation point
        });
    }

    markArticulationPoints(nodes, nodes[root], 0); // start DFS algorithm
    
    // Collect articulation points from meta data
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < adj.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].isArticulation) result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
}
        
// Build adjacency list for example graph, but with undirected edges
let adj = buildAdjacencyList(14, [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 4],
    [2, 5],
    [4, 5],
    [4, 6],
    [3, 7],
    [7, 8],
    [6, 9],
    [8, 9],
    [9, 10],
    [10, 11],
    [10, 12],
    [11, 13],
    [12, 13]
]);

let result = getArticulationPoints(adj, 0);

console.log("Articluation points:", ...result);
```